# Eclipse Formatter

Tags: eclipse, formatting

Does anyone knows how can I adjust Eclipse Formatter to align (or wrap) the strings inside brackets?

I would like t`he format keep the code aligned like this:

```
@Component( 
    immediate = true, 
     property = {
        "com.liferay.portlet.display-category=category.sample",
        "com.liferay.portlet.header-portlet-css=/css/main.css",
        "com.liferay.portlet.instanceable=true",
        "javax.portlet.display-name=PortletModule",
        "javax.portlet.init-param.template-path=/",
        "javax.portlet.init-param.view-template=/view.jsp",
        "javax.portlet.name=" + PortletModulePortletKeys.PORTLETMODULE,
        "javax.portlet.resource-bundle=content.Language",
        "javax.portlet.security-role-ref=power-user,user"
    },
    service = Portlet.class
)
```

But when I do save (with formatting on save actions), the code auto adjusts to this:

```
@Component(
    immediate = true,
    property = { "com.liferay.portlet.display-category=category.sample",
            "com.liferay.portlet.header-portlet-css=/css/main.css", "com.liferay.portlet.instanceable=true",
            "javax.portlet.display-name=PortletModule", "javax.portlet.init-param.template-path=/",
            "javax.portlet.init-param.view-template=/view.jsp",
            "javax.portlet.name=" + PortletModulePortletKeys.PORTLETMODULE,
            "javax.portlet.resource-bundle=content.Language", "javax.portlet.security-role-ref=power-user,user" },
    service = Portlet.class
)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In what language?

Comment: For this example I used Java

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Formatter profile at:

`Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter`

then edit it according to your need, I was also looking to format my Portlet, so I share you [my-formatter.xml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p86NrGoLDP0wNhYsLWMDnW_2woOI2nhf/view?usp=sharing), just import it and edit the Maximum line width as you need (inside the Line Wrapping options), 91 works for me.

I hope this will help.